# For Mountain Lion, how does Apple define the Transparent App Lifecycle (TAL)?

Tags: macos

## Definition

Apple's [talagent(8) OS X Manual Page](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man8/talagent.8.html) (2010-09-01, long before Lion was released) mentions but **does not define** the *Transparent App Lifecycle feature*.

Some time before Lion was released, I understood that the TAL comprised:

- auto save
- versions
- resume.

Now, I'm not so sure. (Suspect that versions are not strictly speaking within the TAL, because not all apps that support the cycle also support versions.)

Please, can anyone give a better answer than the one below?

Something shorter and more definite – maybe with reference to a single e-mail or page from Apple – will be ideal. Thanks.

### Side note, an issue with 10.8

```
macbookpro08-centrim:~ gjp22$ sw_vers
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.8
BuildVersion:   12A269
macbookpro08-centrim:~ gjp22$ man talagent
macbookpro08-centrim:~ gjp22$ which talagent
macbookpro08-centrim:~ gjp22$ talagent
-bash: talagent: command not found
macbookpro08-centrim:~ gjp22$
```

– the command can not be run manually as described in the manual. I'll feed a bug report to Apple. Instead, for example:

```
/System/Library/CoreServices/talagent -dump Finder
```

Comment: Grahahm, can you rewrite the first sentence, there seems to be something missing

Comment: Much better. I'm still not sure whether the question is answerable but we can discuss this in Chat if necessary.

Comment: … now [in Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5703617#5703617) …

Answer (score 1):

## Lion

**Carbon Framework Release Notes** (2011-04-11, three months before the OS was released) placed three things under [Transparent App Lifecycle](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/Carbon/RN-CarbonFramework/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010634-CH1-DontLinkElementID_1) in relation to a seed of the OS:

- persistent state
- sudden termination
- automatic termination.

## Mountain Lion

In **Mac App Programming Guide: The Core App Design** (2012-07-23, two days before the OS was released) the [app life cycle](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/MOSXAppProgrammingGuide/CoreAppDesign/CoreAppDesign.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010543-CH3-SW10) is:

> … the progress of an app from its launch through its termination. …

then [automatic and sudden termination](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/MOSXAppProgrammingGuide/CoreAppDesign/CoreAppDesign.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010543-CH3-SW22) are:

> … techniques that make the termination of an app transparent …

(Unsurprisingly, no mention of Carbon in that guide.)

---

### Summary

Maybe the 2010 man page for `talagent`, in both Lion and Mountain Lion, uses an expression (Transparent App Lifecycle) that was outdated before Lion was released.